# Complex Regression Model in Python

Tags: python, model, regression, data-analysis, non-linear-regression

For a project I am working on, I need to find a model for the data graphed below that includes a sine or cosine component (hard to tell from the image but the data does follow a trig-like function for each period, although the amplitude/max/mins are changing).

[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1J8zA.png)

I originally planned on finding a simple regression model for my data using Desmos before I saw how complex the data was, but alas, I do not think I am capable of determining what equation to use without the help of Python. I don't have much experience with regression in Python, I've only done basic linear modeling where I knew the type of equation and was just determining the coefficients/constants. Could anyone offer a guiding example, git code, or resources that would be useful for this?

Comment: Let me know if the below response is any helpful

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty generic and looking at the graph, we cannot tell much about the data to give you a more detailed answer, but i'd say have a look at OLS 
https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.html

You could also look at scikit learn for the various regression models it provides.
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html

Essentially,these packages will help you figure our the equation you are looking to have for your data.

Also, looks like your graph has an outlier ? Please note regression is very sensitive to outliers, so you may want to handle those data points before fitting the model.